# Как заменить кодировку всех файлов в папке. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: кодировка, ubuntu

Для сайта скачал шаблон, всё работает, только кодировку нужно поменять во всех файлах. Как можно это сделать? В ручную нет желания.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find /<тут путь к папке>/ -type f -exec iconv -f <начальная кодировка> -t <результирующая кодировка> -o {}.utf8 {} \;
```

в папке и подпапках появятся файлы с расширением .utf8 (я просто предположил, что результирующая будет utf8, поэтому так и назвал), которые будут сконвертированными.

Comment: и чтоб совсем полно    iconv -lдаст список поддерживаемых кодировок

Answer (score 4):

```
iconv -o output.file -f UTF-8 -t WINDOWS-1251 input.file
```

f - from; t - to